# How to make dodge in geom_bar agree with dodge in geom_errorbar, geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I have a dataset where measurements are made for different groups at different days.

I want to have side by side bars representing the measurements at the different days for the different groups with the groups of bars spaced according to day of measurement with errorbars overlaid to them.

I'm having trouble with making the dodging in `geom_bar` agree with the dodge on `geom_errorbar`.

Here is a simple piece of code:

```
days          = data.frame(day=c(0,1,8,15));
groups        = data.frame(group=c("A","B","C","D", "E"), means=seq(0,1,length=5));


my_data       = merge(days, groups);


my_data$mid   = exp(my_data$means+rnorm(nrow(my_data), sd=0.25));
my_data$sigma = 0.1;


png(file="bar_and_errors_example.png", height=900, width=1200);
plot(ggplot(my_data, aes(x=day, weight=mid, ymin=mid-sigma, ymax=mid+sigma, fill=group)) +
     geom_bar      (position=position_dodge(width=0.5))                                   +
     geom_errorbar (position=position_dodge(width=0.5), colour="black")                   +
     geom_point    (position=position_dodge(width=0.5), aes(y=mid, colour=group)));
dev.off();
```

In the plot, the errorsegments appears with a fixed offset from its bar (sorry, no plots allowed for newbies even if ggplot2 is the subject).

When binwidth is adjusted in `geom_bar`, the offset is not fixed and changes from day to day.

Notice, that `geom_errorbar` and `geom_point` dodge in tandem. 
How do I get `geom_bar` to agree with the other two?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

The alignment problems are due, in part, to your bars not representing the data you intend. The following lines up correctly:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=day, weight=mid, ymin=mid-sigma, ymax=mid+sigma, fill=group)) +
     geom_bar      (position=position_dodge(), aes(y=mid), stat="identity") +
     geom_errorbar (position=position_dodge(width=0.9), colour="black") +
     geom_point    (position=position_dodge(width=0.9), aes(y=mid, colour=group))
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't find position.dodge(), is this been replaced by position='dodge'? I have a similar problem and have used your solution but unless I set width of the error bars close to 1 the error bars don't line up with the geom_bars.

Comment: @HermanToothrot I just checked and `position_dodge` is a function in `ggplot2` version 2.2.1 (which is the most current version as of writing this comment). I would point out that the separator in the function name is an underscore (`_`), not a dot (`.`). That may be why your code did not find it.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I guess what I am wondering is what is the difference between position=position_dodge() and position="dodge"?

Comment: @HermanToothrot I don't think there is any difference, but I can't say that for sure.

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but since i ran into the problem today, i want to add the following:

In

```
 geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.9), stat = "identity") + 
   geom_errorbar( position = position_dodge(width=0.9), colour="black")
```

the `width`-argument within `position_dodge` controls the dodging width of the things to dodge from each other. However, this produces whiskers as wide as the bars, which is possibly undesired. 
An additional width-argument outside the position_dodge controls the width of the whiskers (and bars):

```
 geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.9), stat = "identity", width=0.7) + 
   geom_errorbar( position = position_dodge(width=0.9), colour="black", width=0.3)
```

Comment: I have noticed this problem but using width changes the position of the whiskers and now they are not lined up anymore with the bars

Answer (score 5):

sometimes you put `aes(x=tasks,y=val,fill=group)` in `geom_bar` rather than `ggplot`.  This causes the problem since ggplot looks forward `x` and you specify it by the location of each group.

Answer (score 4):

The first change I reformatted the code according to the [advanced R style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html).

```
days <- data.frame(day=c(0,1,8,15))

groups <- data.frame(
    group=c("A","B","C","D", "E"), 
    means=seq(0,1,length=5)
    )

my_data <- merge(days, groups)

my_data$mid <- exp(my_data$means+rnorm(nrow(my_data), sd=0.25))
my_data$sigma <- 0.1
```

Now when we look at the data we see that day is a factor and everything else is the same.

```
str(my_data)
```

To remove blank space from the plot I converted the day column to factors. CHECK that the levels are in the proper order before proceeding.

```
my_data$day <- as.factor(my_data$day) 
levels(my_data$day)
```

The next change I made was defining y in your `aes` arguments. As I'm sure you are aware, this lets ggplot know where to look for y values. Then I changed the position argument to "dodge" and added the `stat="identity"` argument. The `"identity"` argument tells ggplot to plot y at x. `geom_errorbar` inherits the dodge position from `geom_bar` so you can leave it unspecified, but `geom_point` does not so you must specify that value. The default dodge is `position_dodge(.9)`.

```
ggplot(data = my_data, 
 aes(x=day,
     y= mid, 
     ymin=mid-sigma, 
     ymax=mid+sigma,       
     fill=group)) +
   geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") + 
   geom_errorbar( position = position_dodge(), colour="black") +
   geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9), aes(y=mid, colour=group))
```

[image]