# Reposition geom_errorbar on a faceted bargraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have found a lot of questions that deal with repositioning error bars in `ggplot2`, but none that have my particular problem. I hope this isn't a duplicate!

I have a faceted barplot, where I am trying to add in error bars for confidence intervals that have already been calculated. The arguments `stat` and `position` don't seem to be having any effect, whether they are in the `aes()` argument or just with `geom_errorbar()`. Here is what I am working with:

```
> dput(anthro.bp)
structure(list(Source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("PED", "RES"), class = "factor"), 
Response = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"
), class = "factor"), Value = c(0.5043315, 0.03813694, 0.20757498, 
0.249956615, 0.9232598, 0.0142572, 0.0537258, 0.008757155, 
0.897265, 0.03153401, 0.06610772, 0.005093254, 0.8360081, 
0.03893782, 0.0370325, 0.088021559), Distance = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Near", "Far"), class = "factor"), UCI = c(0.5853133, 
0.07247573, 0.27357566, 0.32335335, 0.9744858, 0.03844421, 
0.08841988, 0.04262752, 0.9422062, 0.0540748, 0.09600908, 
0.03348959, 1.2445932, 0.11196198, 0.10133358, 0.52272511
), LCI = c(0.4233497, 0.003798153, 0.1415743, 0.17655988, 
0.8720338, -0.009929805, 0.01903172, -0.02511321, 0.8523238, 
0.008993231, 0.03620636, -0.02330308, 0.427423, -0.034086335, 
-0.02726858, -0.34668199)), .Names = c("Source", "Response", 
"Value", "Distance", "UCI", "LCI"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

anthro.bp[,4]<-factor(anthro.bp[,4], levels=c("Near","Far"))
bp <- ggplot(anthro.bp, aes(Value, fill=Response))
bp + geom_bar(aes(x=Source,y=Value), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LCI,ymax=UCI), stat="identity", position="dodge",width=0.25) +
   facet_wrap(~Distance) +
   labs(x="Disturbance Source", y="Mean Probability")
```

I have also tried to use `position=position_dodge(width=1)`, again both within the `aes()` argument and outside of that in the `geom_errorbar()` command. My graph is as follows in the link (I don't have a high enough reputation to embed images yet, apologies!).

[image: Faceted bar graph with incorrectly positioned error bars]

I'm also getting two error messages:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
>   position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
>   2: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
>   position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals

This is the first time that I have used ggplot2 outside of a classroom environment, so constructive criticism is highly encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason which I am not clear on, ggplot2 is dodging your bars and error bars by different values. I got around this by manually specifying the dodging width. Also you've set the y and x aesthetics only geom_bar. Note where they are placed now. Lastly, stat='identity' is not needed for the geom_errorbar call.

```
bp <- ggplot(anthro.bp, aes(x=Source,y=Value, fill=Response))
bp + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LCI,ymax=UCI), position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),width=0.25) +
  facet_wrap(~Distance) +
  labs(x="Disturbance Source", y="Mean Probability")
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [How to make dodge in geom_bar agree with dodge in geom_errorbar, geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050516/how-to-make-dodge-in-geom-bar-agree-with-dodge-in-geom-errorbar-geom-point)

is it what you wanted?

```
anthro.bp$dmin <-  anthro.bp$Value - anthro.bp$LCI
anthro.bp$dmax <- anthro.bp$UCI - anthro.bp$Value

ggplot(data=anthro.bp, aes(x=Source, ymin=Value-dmin, ymax=Value+dmax, fill=Response)) +
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), aes(y=Value), stat="identity") +
geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), colour="black") + facet_wrap(~Distance) + labs(x="Disturbance Source", y="Mean Probability")
```

[image]

Comment: Right idea, but calculating each leg of the error bars seems to add an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main problem was the undefined x value (Source) in the aes of bp.

```
bp <- ggplot(anthro.bp, aes(x=Source,y=Value, fill=Response))
bp + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LCI,ymax=UCI),width=0.25, stat="identity", position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
facet_wrap(~Distance) +
labs(x="Disturbance Source", y="Mean Probability")
```