# How to dodge geom_errorbar and change its width at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2

The only prior question I could find was [this one from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050516/how-to-make-dodge-in-geom-bar-agree-with-dodge-in-geom-errorbar-geom-point) but it doesn't seem to help in my case.

I want to plot the means of groups by subgroup using colors. I want to display error bars (confidence intervals) around the means. And I want the error bars to be less wide than the default.

Example code which data from iris (random data used for the `fill` variable):

```
library(ggplot2)

#data
df_sum = structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", 
                                                                         "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), fillvar = c("A", 
                                                                                                                                    "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), mean = c(1.43636363636364, 1.48214285714286, 
                                                                                                                                                                       4.16666666666667, 4.34615384615385, 5.49130434782609, 5.6037037037037
                                                                                                                                    ), n = c(22, 28, 24, 26, 23, 27), se = c(0.0429161341346969, 
                                                                                                                                                                             0.0281969506722072, 0.103676382414373, 0.0830626768411882, 0.112273142983994, 
                                                                                                                                                                             0.109320809356896), groupvar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), 
               ci_bar = c(2.07961384472768, 2.05183051648029, 2.06865761041905, 
                          2.0595385527533, 2.07387306790403, 2.05552943864287)), .Names = c("Species", 
                                                                                            "fillvar", "mean", "n", "se", "groupvar", "ci_bar"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                               -6L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = groupvar, y = mean, fill = fillvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci_bar*se, ymax = mean + ci_bar*se), position = position_dodge(), width = .2) +
  xlab("Species") + ylab("Petal.Length")
```

Which produces:
[image]

We see the problem. The error bars are dodged, but due to the `width` setting, they are not dodged far enough.

If we plot without the `width` setting:

```
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = groupvar, y = mean, fill = fillvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci_bar*se, ymax = mean + ci_bar*se), position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("Species") + ylab("Petal.Length")
```

We get:
[image]

Which is what we expect, but the errors bars are too wide for my taste.

The problem seems to be that `position_dodge` has a `width` parameter and so does `geom_errorbar`. If one puts `width=0.2` in the `geom_errorbar`, it gets forwarded to `position_dodge` as well which causes the dodge-offset problem. Notice that if one instead sets `width` inside `position_dodge`, it does not get forwarded to `geom_errorbar` (which is outside). This thus only results in the offset being off without the error bars' width changing:

```
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = groupvar, y = mean, fill = fillvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci_bar*se, ymax = mean + ci_bar*se), position = position_dodge(width = .2)) +
  xlab("Species") + ylab("Petal.Length")
```

[image]

This is the reverse of what I want. The question then seems to be how to set `width=0.2` inside `geom_errorbar` without ggplot2 forwarding it automatically to `position_dodge`.

I only found a slight hacking solution, which is to set the `width` to the default value (which seems to be 0.9) inside `position_dodge` to prevent it from getting filled in with the value from `geom_errorbar`:

```
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = groupvar, y = mean, fill = fillvar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - ci_bar*se, ymax = mean + ci_bar*se), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .2) +
  xlab("Species") + ylab("Petal.Length")
```

Which works as intended:
[image]

Is there a non-hack solution to this problem?

Comment: By default, the amount of dodging is calculated just so that overlapping is avoided *in the same geom*. You want the same amount of dodging in different geoms and thus you need to specify it manually (which is not a "hack"). See the last example in `help("position_dodge")`.

Comment: [A more thorough description of the `width` argument in `position_dodge`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge/35102486#35102486).