# ggplot2 - How to center confidence interval bars on bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

this has been asked on other posts, but I have not figured out how to use `position_dodge` correctly.

How can I center each CI bar in each bar on the graph?

```
df <- structure(list(Ano = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2016, 2016, 2016), 
               Grupo = c("Controle", "Tratado", "Total", 
                         "Controle", "Tratado", "Total"), 
               Margem_Mediana = c(4.4,3.1, 4.2, 3.8, 2.5, 3.6), 
               Erro_Padrao = c(0.0236, 0.0460, 0.0214, 0.0257, 0.0478, 0.0231)), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Ano", "Grupo", "Margem_Mediana", "CI"))


ggplot(df, aes(x = Ano, y = Margem_Mediana, fill = Grupo)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, Grupo != 'Total'),
                         position = position_dodge(), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_errorbar(data = subset(df, Grupo != 'Total'),
                              aes(ymin = Margem_Mediana - CI,
                    ymax = Margem_Mediana + CI),
                width = 1.5,
                size = 0.5)
```

Comment: Please revise your code, change `df <- ` to `graf_votos <-` and `.Names = c("Ano", "Grupo", "Margem_Mediana", "CI")` to `.Names = c("Ano", "Grupo", "Margem_Mediana", "Erro_Padrao")`

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

Add `position = position_dodge()` argument in your `geom_errorbar` and specify your bar `width`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Ano, y = Margem_Mediana, fill = Grupo)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(df, Grupo != 'Total'),
           width = 1.5, 
           position = position_dodge(), 
           stat = 'identity') +
  geom_errorbar(data = subset(df, Grupo != 'Total'),
                aes(ymin = Margem_Mediana - CI,
                    ymax = Margem_Mediana + CI),
                width = 1.5,
                position = position_dodge(),
                size = 0.5)
```

After some searching (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050516/how-to-make-dodge-in-geom-bar-agree-with-dodge-in-geom-errorbar-geom-point) and [this page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html)), the code can be further improved,

```
ggplot(subset(df, Grupo != 'Total'), 
       aes(x = as.factor(Ano), y = Margem_Mediana, fill = Grupo)) +
    geom_bar(width = 0.8, 
             position = position_dodge(), 
             stat = 'identity') +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Margem_Mediana - CI,
                      ymax = Margem_Mediana + CI), 
                  width = 0.4, 
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) + 
    xlab('Ano')
```

You can also control the position and width of the error bars using the `width` argument in `position_dodge()` and `geom_errorbar()`

If you want to center the error bars, you may need to specify the `width` in `geom_bar()` say `width = 0.8` (looks like 0.9 is the default) and apply the same value in `position_dodge(width = 0.8)` inside `geom_errorbar()` (use 0.9 if you don't set the `width` in `geom_bar`). And `width` in `geom_errorbar` will tell ggplot the width of the error bars.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can center it without having the intervals not with the same width as the bar?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I have edited my answer, but it still needs manual setting to center the error bar.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I have added more details. Hope it is clear enough.