# Geom_point and geom_errorbar not aligning to each-other

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and have a problem with ggplot and the following dataset (chosen as representative from larger set) where `geom_errorbar` bars do not align with the mean point (using geom_point) and in several cases the horizontal bars do not align with the vertical bar in `geom_errorbar`, so that instead of coming out as an "I" with cross bars at top and bottom, the crossbars are separated from the vertical line or off-center.

I have looked at all the man pages for `ggplot`, `geom_point`, `geom_errorbar`, `position_jitter` (dodge, jitterdodge). I have also tried a bunch of things from here, such as altering the aesthetics within the `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar` calls (e.g. [How to make dodge in geom_bar agree with dodge in geom_errorbar, geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050516/how-to-make-dodge-in-geom-bar-agree-with-dodge-in-geom-errorbar-geom-point))

Here's a basic data set:

```
df <- structure(list(
Test = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "D"), 
mean = c(1, 100.793684, 1, 1, 51.615601, 1, 2.456456), 
sd = c(1, 2.045985, 1, 1, 4.790053, 1, 4.250668), 
lower = c(2, 102.839669, 2, 2, 56.405654, 2, 6.707124), 
upper = c(0, 98.747699, 0, 0, 46.825548, 0, -1.79421)), 
row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now the code I am using:

```
subplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Test, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(aes(x= Test, y = mean), 
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                width = 0.1,
                position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2)) 
subplot
```

This is what I get:

[image: Output of code above]

I suspect it is something basic that I have missed. I have used the same code in line plots and other scatter plots and it has been fine, so I am lost as to what I have done. I have tested it on two different installations of R on separate computers too.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,

```
Test = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "D")
mean = c(1, 100.793684, 1, 1, 51.615601, 1, 2.456456)
sd = c(1, 2.045985, 1, 1, 4.790053, 1, 4.250668)
lower = (mean+sd)
upper = (mean-sd)
range = 1:length(Test)

df <- data.frame(Test,mean,sd,lower,upper,range)
```

then

```
subplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Test, y = mean,group=range)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) 
subplot
```

[image: image of plot]

Comment: Thanks for the help. That also doesn't work with the full dataset, though I'm working on a solution along those lines now.

Answer (score 2):

I posted this data set and problem to the [ggplot Github page](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2941). It seems that I was indeed missing something simple - I needed to set seed for the `geom_` calls to consistently jitter for each point. However it seems that there is an issue with `geom_errorbar`, as setting seed does not fix the crossbar problem.

Upon further investigation (from the Github team) it seems that the cross-bars are being jittered independently of the line. There is a work around (as of 23/10/18) to fix this. In the mean-time use `position_dodge` or `geom_linerange`.

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = Test, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(aes(x= Test, y = mean), 
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2, seed = 123))+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2, seed = 123))
```

Thanks to all for their help.

Comment: `position_dodge` is a better approach for this problem than `position_jitter`, as `position_dodge` allows you to control the spacing between points with a given `Test` value, rather than having it randomly determined by jittering.

Comment: Quite right, `position_dodge` does work well for this approach. However, my full dataset is much larger and `position_dodge` does not allow me to represent each point clearly and has not resolved the issue with the wandering cross-bars. I have tried his approach on my full dataset, now I'll try yours.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `position_jitter` is getting applied differently to the different components of the errorbars. That seems like a bug.

Here's a workaround that might accomplish your goals more directly. Add a column (I'm calling it `version` here) to distinguish between multiple runs of one Test, `group` by that column, and then use `position_dodge` to avoid overlaps.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Test) %>% 
  mutate(version = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()

subplot <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = Test, y = mean, group = version)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) 
subplot
```

[image]

Alternatively, we could use facet_grid and have the width change depending upon the number of tests, which will make the error bar widths consistent.

```
subplot <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = version, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  facet_grid(.~Test, space = "free_x", shrink = T, scales = "free_x")
subplot
```

[image]

Another approach would be to use a discrete scale, as you mention, perhaps by using <strike>`interaction(Test, version)`</strike> a variable combining Test and version to give the same width to each run. (I couldn't get the ordering to be by Test when using the `interaction` approach.)

```
df2 <- df %>% 
group_by(Test) %>% 
  mutate(version = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(label = paste(Test, version)) %>%
  ungroup()

subplot <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = label, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
subplot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work on the full dataset, where I have a bunch more variables. I'll keep working on it. Any idea as to why the width of the crossbars varies between the points (c.f. "B" and the ones on "A/1"). I see that on my question and answer below too?

Comment: I've added a variation using facets, which allows for error bars to stay same width regardless of number of versions of each test.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The full version of my data set is already faceted for another feature. I initially thought the problem was something to do with my faceting, but now I wonder if I can convert my scale to continuous from discrete and see if that helps.

Comment: If you need to preserve the faceting for something else, then using a discrete scale might be your best option. I've updated my response to show one.